# CMake exclude file from build according to configuration

Tags: c++, cmake

I am migrating an existing C++ project to CMake.
In this project some source files are marked as `Excluded from Build` in Visual Studio General Configuration Properties **only in Release mode**.

I try to find a way to reproduce this behaviour with my `CMakeLists.txt`. So far I've tried using `target_sources()` with generator expressions:

```
set(_srcs Doctor.cpp Clara.cpp)
set(_headers Doctor.hpp Clara.hpp)

add_library(Tardis SHARED ${_srcs} ${_headers})

target_sources(Tardis PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Dalek.cpp>)
```

But I end with a CMake error at Generate step:

```
Target "Tardis" has source files which vary by configuration.  This is not supported by the "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" generator.
```

I could still wrap the content of my *exclude-me-in-release-mode* files with a big `#ifdef _DEBUG` but I am actually looking for any solution which wouldn't make me modify my source files from the original project.

I use CMake 3.8 and the minimum required is 3.7.

Have a nice day !

Comment: If in release mode, then just add the file to `_srcs`?

Comment: Well not with MSVC. It's a multiple configuration IDE. Contrary to Makefiles Generators where Debug or Release is set at generation step, with MSVC this is at build step. At that moment `_srcs` is already defined and may not be changed. Thus the generator expression in order to change the source files at build step.

Comment: I could not even test this solution =) with Visual Studio, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` expands to nothing.

Comment: Thanks. So far I know about generator expressions and `_<CONFIG>` suffixes on some property names. But `SOURCES` is a read-only property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create separate static library for the conditionally included sources. The library can then be linked dependent on the configuration via the [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html) command, for example:

```
add_library(TardisDebugOnlyHelper STATIC ${_debug_only_srcs} ${_debug_only_headers})
add_library(Tardis SHARED ${_srcs} ${_headers})
target_link_libraries(Tardis debug TardisDebugOnlyHelper)
```

(disclaimer: I didn't test that yet)

Comment: Yes I was thinking about this one too. That's not perfect in the way it changes a little bit the former project architecture but I think it's the nicest solution so far.